# What all all possible summes that yeild number N called

Tags: number-theory

Are all possible sums of a number a studied subject and if so -- what is this are called.

For example let N=5 then all possible sums would be:

1. 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
2. 1 + 1 + 1 + 2
3. 1 + 1 + 3
4. 1 + 4
5. 1 + 2 + 2
6. 2 + 3

Comment: They are called partitions of $N$.  They are studied.

Comment: If order does not matter, they are called partitions. If order matters (so for example $1+2+1$ is different from $1+1+2$) they are called compositions.

Comment: Sure, but I feel like I didn't do any work.  I can't tell you much about them... lol

Comment: My next question was going to be is there any relation to Primes and Partitions -- just saw there is a lot of work in that area :-) -- I wish I had majored in Math.

Comment: Besides "partition" lookup "Young tableau", which is a graphical representation of a partition. Partitions are used in areas other than number theory. In particular, partitions and Young tableau are prominent in representation theory and therefore appear in quantum mechanics.

Comment: Would you include $5+0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possible sums of a number $n$ are called [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) of $n$. As Andre Nicolas has said in the comments, if order matters, they are called compositions.

The partitions on $ n$ correspond to the set of solutions $(d_1,d_2,...,d_n)$ to the Diophantine equation

$$\sum^n_{i=1}id_i=n$$ 
The Euler transform $b_n$ gives the number of partitions of $n$ into integer parts of which there are $a_n$ different types of parts of size n.

In reply to your comment: A prime partition of a positive integer $n\geq2$ is a set of primes $p_i$ which sum to $n$.

Answer (score 3):

They are called partitions of $N$.